# CRON Expression to run half past the hour

Tags: schedulebatch, cron

I understand how to make a job run on the hour and every hour. Is there a way to schedule the job to run every hour, but half past the hour e.g. 2:30, 3:30, 4:30 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via code. The following code will schedule if for half an hour. Try this one, it should work

```
ProcessAccs pa= new ProcessAccs();
String cronStr = '0 30 * * * ?';
System.schedule('Process Job', cronStr, pa);
```

Comment: It's seems like a tricky one. Background is we have a load of hourly jobs running on the hour which take around 15 minutes to complete. If we can staggers these to run off the hour, but still hourly. Then we can do more. We are looking to implement flexible queue (whatever the feature is called, but cannot do that immediately)

Comment: One thing I can suggest is, until I come up with a better one is look at Queueable Apex, I have not used it myself but I am exploring it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to run every thirty minutes using the [System.schedule](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) method.

The code below will get your scheduled job to run every 30 minutes

```
String sch = '0 30 * * * *';
System.schedule('My Jobs scheduled name', sch, new MyJob());
```

The schedule is in the format

> Seconds - Minutes - Hours - Day_of_month - Month - Day_of_week - optional_year

See [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) for more information.